# Require a comment when deleting an answer or a question

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I have had to delete a few questions and answers and really wanted to make mods know why I deleted them, as it stands I would have to revive my answer to explain the reason. With questions once its gone its gone.

It would be nice to have a little field that allows you to select why you deleted something:

Eg. "Deleted cause I answered the wrong question", "Deleted cause I made a trivial logic mistake" etc..

Comment: As long as it's optional, it's fine by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit your answer or put it in a comment before you delete it. Very few things in the system are really deleted - mods and users with 10k+ rep can still see deleted questions, answers, and their attached comments, so there's no need to create an additional mechanism to do this.

Comment: With a question I can not get it back. Once deleted it is gone. With answers I often forget and then have to go through a multi-step process

Comment: True, but I don't think that's reason enough to create a whole system so you don't forget to leave a note, especially since a note is neither requested nor required. Are you afraid that other people will judge you by your deleted posts unless you qualify them?

Comment: It's more that I'm afraid people will find it odd that I deleted something ... and would like to qualify the reason