# Are comments on deleted answers readable by the poster?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers

Often when I delete a (very) inappropriate answer I will leave a comment stating why it has been deleted, but **I'm not sure whether the OP is able to read the comments on the deleted answer.**

I've read two related questions on [notifying the OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39741/notify-answer-op-when-answer-is-deleted) and [requiring a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7022/require-a-comment-when-deleting-an-answer-or-a-question) when deleting an answer, but couldn't really find an answer.

It wouldn't be useful to leave such a comment if the OP couldn't read it. Although I would still comment to notify other mods or high rep users of why I did it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are

Anyone that can see a deleted post can see its comments too, and you can see your own deleted answers (as long as you remember which question it was on, because all links dissapear from your profile).

You cannot, however, see your own deleted *questions* if you are not a moderator or 10k user

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Downvoter's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47527/are-comments-on-deleted-answers-readable-by-the-poster/47528#47528), note that you don't see a link to your own deleted answer (in your profile stats page) unless you have over a certain amount of rep.  (10k+? I can't recall the amount needed.)

I've been leaving comments on inappropriate answers that need to be deleted, then flagging for mod attention requesting to "wait 2 hrs then delete".  The comment I leave usually includes something to the effect of *"this post will be deleted shortly"*.

1. This gives the OP a little time to see the comment on a non-deleted answer, and possibly encourages the OP to delete the answer on their own.
2. This also gives *other* users a chance to see the comment and, hopefully, learn something about the way the site works.

I don't bother with that for old, inappropriate answers, but for very recent posts, especially by new users, I think it's beneficial.

Comment: Ah, now they didn't mention that before! I'll leave the flagged answers open for them to read then ;-)

Comment: @Ivo: yeah, sorry 'bout that.  [they're not long enuff for a full explanation...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47881/increase-character-limit-for-the-reason-field-of-requires-moderator-attention)

Answer (score 0):

Only if the OP can access the question (which right now means he didn't close the window and refreshed after it was closed).

Comment: But you can always see you own deleted *answers*, right?