# Minimum character limits in comments / Moderator flagging

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, flags, character-limit

There is a character limit in comments, that makes it appear that it can be circumvented by using spaces.
This no longer works, as the server will detect the empty spaces i leave at the end of my comment and still whine about it.
Now when i open a flag for moderators, there is also a minimum character limit.  This one appears to be circumventable by adding spaces to the end, as i get a "We'll look into it" message(Moderators should have received a flag with contents "Testing        ".
In the interests of standardization across the board, are we gonna fix this one too?

Comment: Please stop fixing that bug, I can never remember the workarounds.

Comment: @Lance: Then flag for `..........` (Don't try this at home).

Comment: There is still a work-around for the comment bug.

Comment: In what case would I need less then 10 characters in a flag? Add a "Thank you" and you can send it away (and made a mod happy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be pushed tonight.  Thank you for your diligence :)

Comment: Any chance you can take a look at this too, please? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47881/increase-character-limit-for-the-reason-field-of-requires-moderator-attention