# Flagging comments not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please tell me how many characters I have left in the comment flagging dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99959/please-tell-me-how-many-characters-i-have-left-in-the-comment-flagging-dialog)

Over on English Language and Usage, I clicked on the flag beside [a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27057/is-it-rude-to-call-a-gay-person-homosexual/29089#29089). A box appeared with a number of options. I selected "other". A text box appeared. So far, everything's working. I entered some text. No problem.

> So completely off-topic that I suspect that it's a copy-paste from
>   elsewhere on the site by a spam-bot.
>
> On the other hand, the user's other two interactions with the site
>   (one answer and one other comment) seem relevant, so maybe this was
>   simply mistakenly posted in the wrong place.

I clicked on "Flag comment". Nothing happened. Nothing at all.

Comment: Here is a comment that can be used for testing.

Comment: @Jon. Hmm. Works here. Definitely didn't work on English.SE a couple of minutes ago.