# Would comment be received by @user if I delete the post?

Tags: discussion, comment-replies

I have asked a question. A user left a comment which addresses my problem (a confirmed bug with a specific version of a software). I wish to thank the user with a comment and delete the post now that it is no longer useful or meaningful. Can the user still receive my comment after I have deleted the post? Or should I wait for the user to log on again before deleting?

Comment: Also see [Are comments on deleted answers readable by the poster?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47527)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user will not be able to see the comment once your post is deleted, unless the user has more than [10k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

I believe that even for 10k+ users the comment would be removed from their inbox; they would have to explicitly look up your post (for questions that means they need to know the exact URL).

Generally, if I am going to delete a post but want to leave a comment I want someone to see, I wait a day or so, and include something along the lines of "I'll delete this post in a day or so". You still cannot be certain anyone will have seen your comment; you could monitor their 'seen' value on their profile but that's not a guarantee they actually read their responses.

Comment: Thank you. Noted, then I have to wait.